# cannot see android files on pc in specific folders

Tags: android, usb-storage

When I plug my android phone into my PC and use Windows Explorer to look at the files on the phone there is a certain folder where I can't view the files. If I then go to my phone and cut and paste the files into another folder I can then get to them in Windows.

There's an easy workaround then, but does it indicate there is something wrong with my SD card? I obviously don't want to reformat is because it is used by lots of the apps on my phone.

Comment: Check whether the folders are being changed to hidden while connecting to PC. Also search the file name after connecting to windows in some cases the folder structure might get changed by default while mounting it in windows

Comment: The folder is definitely not hidden I can see it there is nothing in it. I changed explorer to show all hidden files as well so it's not that. I'll try searching for a file next time I connect to a PC.

Comment: What folder...?

Comment: it is a subfolder of /storage/emulated/0. I have happily been using this folder for weeks and copying files from it. It stopped working recently.